# Best way to store webshop item data as a snapshot when an order is created

Tags: database-design, relational-database, data-integrity

I'm designing the architecture of my application and I'm running into an issue. For the webshop every `Order` entity has a relationship with a `Store` and many `StoreItem`'s. This allows for quick fetching of information when a user wants to view the `Order`.

However, when a `StoreItem` is altered, or even worse, deleted, this information is no longer relevant/available when looking at the `Order` entity. I have two possible solutions for this, and I would like your feedback on them:

1. When an `Order` is created, copy the `Store` and `StoreItem` into `OrderStore` and `OrderStoreItem` entities that will never be changed, even if the original entities are altered or removed. The `Order` will now automatically reference to the `OrderStore` and `OrderStoreItem` entities.
2. When an `Order` is created, copy all necessary data as JSON into special fields in the `Order` entity. Every time data is requested, get the JSON and turn it into data the system can use.

If you know of a better way to do this, feel free to add it. I'm trying to keep everything relational, so no child objects/tables.